# Control display saturation on Linux

Tags: linux, display

What are some ways to programmatically control display saturation on Linux? On Windows, I use f.lux's grayscale mode to desaturate the screen, but on Linux I can only find ways to control hue and brightness through xrandr. I seem to have heard of people enabling grayscale mode in their driver configuration, but what about more fine grained and programmatic control?

Comment: https://justgetflux.com/linux.html ?

Comment: @spikey_richie Linux version of f.lux is less featured than the Windows one. It does not have saturation controls.

Comment: Perhaps the linux kernel doesn't support it, hence it's not in f.lux? Maybe one for the f.lux forums?